systemd fails to run script that otherwise works fine?
I have a golang API that needs to run 24/7 for a nginx proxy backstream.
I have a script..
#!/usr/bin/bash
cd /root/api && go run .

That runs fine manually.
But /etc/systemd/system/api.service fails to start
.service:
[Unit]
Description=A go-lang API for the www frontend

[Service]
Type = simple
ExecStart=/root/api.sh

systemctl status reports
× api.service - A go-lang API for the www frontend
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/api.service; static)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2024-11-21 18:55:03 UTC; 2min 17s ago
   Duration: 118ms
 Invocation: e6e602afee2b4bf6b2d623c15fcbb65e
    Process: 343565 ExecStart=/root/api.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 343565 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Mem peak: 2.8M
        CPU: 50ms


you have no After specified in [Unit] - perhaps your systemd unit is starting too early

As Jaromanda says, you should tell systemd when to start this. You should also specify WHERE the go executable is (but rather than provide the path to the exe a better way is to set the PATH in the environment, e.g. Environment="PATH=/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin" under [Service]).
You should also learn how to check your logs when something goes wrong.
And you should not be installing services under the root home dir, NOR running exposed services as root!

Its not exposed that's the whole point of the nginx layer.

Logs don't provide anything, I know how to check journalctl

I start it manually

Did you check jounrnalctl logs ?
Running as root is not recommended. if you want to run only as root, then try to mention it specifically in your script & try.
It's better to create a separate user to run the API service.
Please add a log file as well to debug, which would make things easier.
